# How to wash impurity away

Tags: muslim-practices, najis

Assalaam-ale-kum,
My question is i have urinary tract infection & find it hard to control my urine sometimes. Today, as i stepped into the bathroom my urine came out. It went on my underwear & trouser. I quickly sat on the bath tub as the toilet was further ahead, some of the urine came out in the bath tub. I splashed water over the bathtub wherever i saw drops of urine & cleaned it. I am not sure if drops of urine went on the floor or on my shoes. There was some water on the floor but i am not sure if it was urine or water from before as it looked clear. I put water in a mug & splashed that area with water aswell. Was that enough to clean the bath tub & floor?
Then i washed only my lower part of the body (private parts, legs & feet) with water & soap & changed my clothes. Am i pure now as i forgot to wash my hands before cleaning myself? I washed my hands at the end. Please answer my question, as i am struggling with really bad OCD & anxiety. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to feel clean enough. You could just wash everything else. The bathroom and your clothes.

And you could take a bath and you are good to go
Urine doesn't make one impure per se, it just makes one dirty and cleanliness is important in Islam that's why ablution is necessary before prayers, why we wash our mouth and everything in between (basic hygiene)

I wish you good luck and I pray you find assistance in Allah for your anxiety ❤️